# find function not recognized by a multiset stl

Tags: c++, stl

So I used a multiset for my programming problem as

```
multiset<pair<int,int> > M;
multiset<pair<int,int> >::iterator it,it2;
```

And inserting values into it using

```
M.insert(make_pair(temp,ind));
```

But now, when I use the find function, to find a value that exists, say

```
it2=M.find(temp);
```

Where temp is an integer, it throws this error:

```
F:\ABC.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
F:\ABC.cpp|42|error: no matching function for call to
'std::multiset<std::pair<int, int> >::find(int&)'|
F:\ABC.cpp|42|note: candidates are:|
```

I have spent days trying to debug this, but to no avail! Can anyone explain why this happens, and suggest a remedy for this?

P.S. I wish to find using only one key value in the multiset!
(Thanks to @Nabla for the suggestion)

Comment: Your `multiset` stores `std::pair<int, int>` objects and you're searching for a single `int`, see the problem here?

Comment: Maybe you wanted a `multimap`, not a `mulitiset`? Please explain how you are going to use this.

Comment: @Nabla I used multimap, but in vain, because multimap sorts by keys, I want values to be sorted by both key-value pair.
Say that I have these elements: 
(10,1),(8,2),(2,3),(2,2),(8,1)
Storing them as a multimap using less qualifier gives me
2 3
2 2
8 2
8 1
10 1

But I want it in the order
2 2
2 3
8 1
8 2
10 1

That is why I used a multiset!

Comment: @user1520427 Then please suggest me how to search using find in multiset, if it requires two values.

Comment: @AbbaShareen `M.find(std::pair<int, int>(i1, i2))` where you want to find the `pair` containing `i1` and `i2`

Comment: But I want it to primarily search it by the key value only! Mutliset provides me the comfort of sorting, but not the find function I wish to use!

Comment: @AbbaShareen You would very much increase your chances for a good answer if you stated that in the question. So your actual question is: How to store sorted by two values, but find by only one? Please edit your question.

Comment: @AbbaShareen In that case you'll want to implement a comparitor for (see the arguments for `multiset` constructor) such that the `multiset` is ordered only by the first value, then you can iterate through until you find a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the container to be sorted by both values, but search by only the first one, here is a suggestion.

```
it = M.lower_bound(pair<int,int>(temp, numeric_limits<int>::min()));
```

This requires you to `#include <limits>`. It will return an iterator to the lowest element equal to or higher than the minimal pair with `temp` as first element. You can then iterate through the set until you have found all pairs with `temp` as first element:

```
while((it != M.end()) && (it->first == temp)) {
     // Do something with the found element in it
     it++;
}
```